# SQL: Select Distinct and Max shows the lowest value instead of the highest

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, max, distinct

In my table `hms_bbr_group` since there are multiple copies of the column `group_id` I am trying to have a query selecting the highest value `id` of each `group_id`, hence the DISTINCT

Table:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzncR.png)

For instance, I want my query to show only `id 61`, `group_id 36`, in `group_name Infection Control` disregarding the other ids since I only want the highest value

My SQL select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (hbg.group_id)
    MAX(hbg.id) AS id,
    hbg.group_id,
    hbg.group_name,
    hbg.group_description,
    hbg.group_type_id,
    hbgt.group_type_name,
    hbg.category_id,
    hbg.effective_start_datetime,
    hbg.created_by,
    hbg.created_datetime,
    hbg.archived_by,
    hbg.archived_datetime
FROM 
    hms_bbr_group hbg
LEFT JOIN 
    hms_bbr_group_type hbgt ON (hbg.group_type_id = hbgt.group_type_id)
GROUP BY 
    hbg.group_id, hbg.group_name, hbg.group_description, 
    hbg.group_type_id, hbgt.group_type_name, hbg.category_id, 
    hbg.effective_start_datetime, hbg.created_by, 
    hbg.created_datetime, hbg.archived_by, hbg.archived_datetime 
ORDER BY 
    hbg.group_id ASC;
```

The important lines here are

```
DISTINCT ON (hbg.group_id)
MAX(hbg.id) AS id
```

My issue is the output shows the lowest id value instead:

SQL query:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmZBl.png)

as you can see from the first screenshot, instead of getting `id 61` on `group_id 36` (highest) I am getting `id 36` (lowest)

to test it out I tried replacing MAX with MIN but the output is still the same.

How come my SQL does not show the MAX id value?

Comment: I added the `postgresql` tag as to my knowledge it's the only DBMS that offers `distinct on()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `DISTINCT ON` is incorrect, and you don't need to be using `GROUP BY` here.  Just list in parentheses in the select clause the column used for considering each group.  Then repeat that column *first* in the `ORDER BY` clause, followed by the column to be used for choosing the first record in each group.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (hbg.group_id)
    hbg.group_id,
    hbg.id AS id,
    hbg.group_name,
    hbg.group_description,
    hbg.group_type_id,
    hbgt.group_type_name,
    hbg.category_id,
    hbg.effective_start_datetime,
    hbg.created_by,
    hbg.created_datetime,
    hbg.archived_by,
    hbg.archived_datetime
FROM hms_bbr_group hbg
LEFT JOIN hms_bbr_group_type hbgt
    ON hbg.group_type_id = hbgt.group_type_id
ORDER BY
    hbg.group_id,
    hbg.id DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you just to clear things out, MAX is not needed since the highest value id is being read by ORDER BY hbg.id DESC?

Comment: Yes, but don't think that just by selecting `MAX` it restricts to only the max ID record; it doesn't.  The alternative to what I posted above would be to use `ROW_NUMBER`, a totally different query.  If you wanted a `GROUP BY` with `MAX` approach, then you would have to join to a subquery which finds the max for each group.

Comment: thanks for the quick lesson, this has been great help

Comment: @GetSomeHelp Well that's what this site is all about.  Good help, high quality answers.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!